# How do you add a span element inside an '<li></li>' menu item in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

If an li has class menu-item-has-children then insert a span element inside of it with an id of 'menu_toggle[x]' where 'x' will increment depending on the number of id's that already exist named 'menu_toggle[x].

Im basically trying to get the static html version of a menu working correctly on wordpress for mobile.

This is a screenshot of the static html and css of what I'm gunning for in my wordpress menu (which btw is identical, using the same css (slightly modified) but has lost the '+' menu_toggle classes which I'm trying to re-create and add in my wp menu now).

[image]

In my wp version,  everything works except when i hide the first ul dropdown (display:none) as I wish to only reveal it via click event using jquery code.

What is the best way to go about this, without 'over engineering' or 'over complicating' this ? I just want the easiest hassle free approach thanks.

Comment: btw in my wp version of this menu,  the first '<li><a></a></li> has an id of menu-item-37,  assigned by default by wp.


i.e - <li id="menu-item-37"><a href="#">Company Overview</a></li>

and what I am trying to do is place a <span> inside the above

i.e - <li id="menu-item-37"><a href="#">Company Overview</a><span id="menu_toggle1" class="menu_toggle">+</span></li>


I believe I'll need to target the li with id 'menu-item-37'...

Comment: The best way would probably be to use your own custom NavWalker. Basic example here: https://gist.github.com/kosinix/5544535

Answer (score 1):

You can use script like this:

```
var clickable = $('.mbnav__state').attr('data-clickable');
    $('.mbnav li:has(ul)').addClass('has-sub');
    $('.mbnav .has-sub>a').after('<em class="mbnav__caret">');
    if (clickable == 'true') {
        $('.mbnav .has-sub>.mbnav__caret').addClass('trigger-caret');
    } else {
        $('.mbnav .has-sub>a').addClass('trigger-caret').attr('href', 'javascript:;');
    }

    /* menu open and close on single click */
    $('.mbnav .has-sub>.trigger-caret').click(function () {
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('is-open')) {
            element.removeClass('is-open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('is-open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('is-open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('is-open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('is-open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
        }
    });
```

https://prnt.sc/1qyjcq8